# How to make permissions to a user on all new tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Supposing, I have two users in Postgres 9.6 named `user1` and `user2`. I want to make permissions to `user2` on any new table created by `user1` without extra explicit grant commands for the created table. In other words, I want to make the following commands work correctly:

1. Giving permissions to `user2` (**I don't know what should be here!**)
2. `CREATE TABLE t1 (id int)` (under `user1`)
3. `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (5)` (under `user2`)

Please, notice, I am not supposed to make any permissions between step 2 and 3.

On step 3 I always have the error:

```
permission denied for relation t1
```

I have tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO user2;
```

and

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user2;
```

without any success.

I also tried:

```
GRANT user1 TO user2
```

and it helped. But I can't consider it as the solution because `user1` may have too high permissions (for example, it can be `postgres`) that I don't want to share with `user2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER user1
GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO user2
```

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Yes, works just fine. There's nothing special about `postgres`; it's just an ordinary role with the superuser flag set. You can drop it and create your own if you want.